# Youtube API get video length and views

Tags: youtube-api

Is this possible? Using Youtube API v3.0 to get video length and views? I can't seem to find anything on it as all the results are for v2.0.

Answer (score 3):

The search endpoint doesn't have a way to return this info yet, but the videos endpoint can if you request the `contentDetails`and the `statistics` in the `part` parameter ... something like this:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails%2Cstatistics&id=voNEBqRZmBc&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

The returned object will have a `duration` attribute that's in ISO 8601 format (under the contentDetails), and a `views` attribute under the statistics.

Comment: Unfortunately the use of `googleapis.com` can be problematic because Chrome blocks access to it as insecure from youtube.com, so you cannot write a userscript that for example, adds the video length to the page so that people can see the length even if Flash is disabled or set to click-to-play. `:-(`