# How to count video length and size in PHP?

Tags: php, video, youtube, ffmpeg

I want to get video details like length, size, frame, height and width from one video url.

I got the video details after download video using ffmpeg but unable to find the details of video from URL.

Here is my download video youtube link.

```
http://r4---sn-np4tjvg2-cvhe.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?fexp=927610%2C935016%2C941300%2C916626%2C936204%2C924606%2C929117%2C929121%2C929906%2C929907%2C929922%2C929923%2C929127%2C929129%2C929131%2C929930%2C936403%2C925724%2C925726%2C936310%2C925720%2C925722%2C925718%2C925714%2C929917%2C906945%2C929933%2C929935%2C920302%2C906842%2C913428%2C920605%2C919811%2C935020%2C935021%2C932309%2C913563%2C919373%2C930803%2C908536%2C932211%2C938701%2C931924%2C934005%2C940501%2C936308%2C909549%2C901608%2C900816%2C912711%2C934507%2C907231%2C936312%2C906001&itag=17&sver=3&expire=1379625974&sparams=algorithm%2Cburst%2Ccp%2Cfactor%2Cgcr%2Cid%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&mt=1379599833&mv=u&id=a1902c59b3e797d1&upn=rjoiIino7rU&factor=1.25&source=youtube&ms=au&algorithm=throttle-factor&burst=40&gcr=in&key=yt1&ip=202.191.214.174&cp=U0hWTlZNU19MTkNONl9OR1dKOlZGT2E1U2xXM0hN&ipbits=8&signature=CEE61FCB88931236269EE8661F62C1D834DCD32E.95869B5D4D79ED6D4D890749A49C228631CD3340
```

Comment: I seriously doubt this will even be possible, especially using PHP. If YouTube had an API for this, that would be the way. But as far as I'm aware, there is nothing of the sort.

Comment: Use ffmpeg to get the video details

Comment: If they don't put it in the URL how can you get it from the URL? What makes you think it is there?

Comment: @Pwner How to get from ffmpeg. Have any example give me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Youtube API get video length and views](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17288087/youtube-api-get-video-length-and-views)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use youtube api

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails%2Cstatistics&id=voNEBqRZmBc&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

[Youtube API get video length and views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17288087/youtube-api-get-video-length-and-views)

Or use json

```
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/(the-video-id)?v=2&alt=json
```